# CSS - li background

Tags: css, html-lists

I want to code this so the active and hover li's appear over the normal li. But what happens is the hover and active li's appear inside the normal li. When I add padding (to hover and active li's) in an attempt to duplicate the size of the normal li, the normal li remains visible and simply expands by the increase padding of the hover and active li and not covered as I need it to be.

Here is my CSS:

/**********************HORIZONTAL NAVS**********************/

```
.menu-horizontal {
    margin: 3px 2px 0.75em;
}
.menu-horizontal ul.top-level {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    clear: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu-horizontal ul.top-level li {
    background: #FEAB27;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 0 25px;
}
.menu-horizontal ul.top-level {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 23px;
    margin-left: 173px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: none;
}

.menu-horizontal ul.top-level li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Verdana,'Magra','Gafata',sans-serif;
    font-size: 102%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu-horizontal ul.top-level li.selected a, .menu-horizontal ul.top-level li a:hover {
    background: #FDCC00;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    text-decoration: underline;


}
.menu-horizontal li ul.second-level {
    display: block;
    left: -999em;
    margin: -1000px 0 0;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0 0 9px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
}

.menu-horizontal li:hover ul.second-level, .menu-horizontal li.hover ul.second-level {
    left: auto;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, or in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your question right, but did you want something like this?

```
.menu-horizontal ul.top-level li.selected, .menu-horizontal ul.top-level li:hover {
background: #FDCC00;
border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
}

.menu-horizontal ul.top-level li a:hover, .menu-horizontal ul.top-level li.selected a {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/svSwA/

If you want to change another element as an A you have to put the :hover selector on it, or you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: thx for spellchecking, it was written with a mobile device :)

Comment: You are welcome, please be aware, that this solution did not work with some older browser